# Remapping keyboard combination to Home/End on linux

Tags: linux, keyboard-layout, gentoo

I would like to remap the key combination <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Left/Right</kbd> to the <kbd>Home</kbd>/<kbd>End</kbd> keys, but I cannot figure out how to do that.

Should it be done with xmodmap? Or with [XKB configuration](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/X_keyboard_extension)?

Comment: What Linux are you wish to make that change? **Archlinux** or **Gentoo**?

Comment: hi @JorgeLuiz, I don't think there is any difference in this case but I am using Gentoo.

Answer (score 1):

assuming you're using X, use xdotool or xvkbd to send keyboard events to the screen.

```
xdotool key Home
```

OR

```
xvkbd -text '\[Home]'
```

to map them, use a keyboard shortcut manager like sxhkd, xbindkeys, or the one built into your DE or WM